# Launch a TCP client and server in the same program (in c)

Tags: c, multithreading, client, tcpclient

I am studying in france ,sorry for my english , i have a project to realize, i program an industreille machine with a client tcp and i have to send the sensor information on tcp server,
I wanted to know how with the threads I could run the client and the server on the same program at the same time,I am not a good programmer please help me ...

client :

```html
/*************    BIBIOTHEQUE   *********************/
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*************      SORTIES   ***********************/
#define EJECTION_PIECE                 0x01   // bit 0
#define ASPIRATION_ONA                 0x02   // bit 1
#define EXPULSION_VENTOUSE             0x04   // bit 2
#define BRAS_POSITION_MAGASINA         0x08   // bit 3
#define BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLEA 0x10   // bit 4  0001 1000  0X18

/*************     ENTREES   ************************/
#define NON_DISPONIBLE                0x01  // bit 0   1   1
#define EJECTION_PIECE_RETRACTE       0x02  // bit 1   1   0
#define EJECTION_PIECE_AVANCE         0x04  // bit 2   0   1
#define ASPIRATION_ON                 0x08  // bit 3   0   0
#define BRAS_POSITION_MAGASIN         0x10  // bit 4   0   0
#define BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE 0x20  // bit 5   0   0
#define RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE            0x40  // bit 6   1   0
#define ASPIRATION_OFF                0x80  // bit 7   1   1

/*************     PORT & IP  ************************/
#define  PORT1  4200
#define  PORT2 4200
#define  IP2   "172.16.1.24"  //serveur Tcp

SOCKADDR_IN info_Trame;
SOCKADDR_IN envoie_donnee_serveur;

/*int nombre_de_caractere;
int nombre_de_caractere_recu ;
int nombre_de_caractere_recu_Capteur;
int nombre_caractere_recu_serveur;
int nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur;
int nombre_de_caractere_Capteur;

char buffer1[50];
//char buffer2[50];
char buffer3[50];
*/

SOCKET configurationTCP(char ip[], uint16_t port)
{
    SOCKET id_de_la_socket;

    WSADATA initialisation_win32; /// Variable pour récupérer la structure d'information sur l'initialisation
    int erreur;

    printf("programme client tcp\n");

    erreur=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&initialisation_win32);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\n impossible d'initialiser Winsock  : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n WSAStartup  réussi ");

    // Ouverture d'une Socket
    //id_de_la_socket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);   /// Ouverture d'une Socket
    id_de_la_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    printf("id socket =%d\n",id_de_la_socket);
    if (id_de_la_socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\n impossible de creer la socket  : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n socket valider \n ");


    // OUVERTURE DE SESSION TCP
    info_Trame.sin_family=AF_INET;
    info_Trame.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
    info_Trame.sin_port = htons(port);
    erreur=connect(id_de_la_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&info_Trame,sizeof(info_Trame));
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\n impossible d'ouvrir la session TCP : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n OUVERTURE DE SESSION TCP : OK \n ");

    return id_de_la_socket;
}



void fermetureTCP(SOCKET id_de_la_socket)
{
    int erreur;

    erreur=shutdown(id_de_la_socket,2); // 2 signifie socket d'émission et d'écoute
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\n Desole, je ne peux pas fermer la session TCP du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n Session TCP : Arreter \n ");

    // FERMETURE DE LA SOCKET
    erreur=closesocket(id_de_la_socket);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\n Desole, je ne peux pas arreter la socket machine du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n Socket machin : Arreter \n");

    // Fermeture de WSAStartup
    erreur=WSACleanup();
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\n Desole, je ne peux pas liberer winsock du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n WSACleanup : OK \n");
    getchar();
}


void ecritureModbus(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char donnees1, unsigned char donnees2)
{
    unsigned char trameModbus[12]= {0x6c ,0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0xff, 0x06,0x9c,0x42};
    unsigned char buffer[50];
    int nombre_de_caractere_recu, i;
    int nombre_de_caractere;

    trameModbus[10] = donnees1;
    trameModbus[11] = donnees2;

    nombre_de_caractere=send(id_de_la_socket,(char *)trameModbus,12,0);

    if (nombre_de_caractere==SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("\n Desole, je n'ai pas envoyer les donnees du a l'erreur : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\n send trame     : OK");

    nombre_de_caractere_recu=recv(id_de_la_socket,(char *)buffer,12,0);
    if (nombre_de_caractere_recu==SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("\n Desole, je n'ai pas recu de donnee de la trame ");
    else
    {
        printf("\nTrame modbus reçue : ");
        for(i=0; i< nombre_de_caractere_recu; i++)
        {
            printf("%x ",buffer[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

unsigned char lectureModbus(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char donnees1, unsigned char donnees2 )  //tram modbus capteur
{
    unsigned char trameModBus_capteur[12]= {0x50, 0xa2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0xff, 0x03, 0xb1, 0x53};
    unsigned char buffer[50];
    int nombre_de_caractere_recu_capteur, i;
    int nombre_de_caractere_capteur;
    trameModBus_capteur[10] = donnees1;
    trameModBus_capteur[11] = donnees2;

    nombre_de_caractere_capteur=send(id_de_la_socket,(char *)trameModBus_capteur,12,0);
    if (nombre_de_caractere_capteur==SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("\nFonction modbus 3 : probleme envoi trame : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nsend trame     : OK\n");

    nombre_de_caractere_recu_capteur=recv(id_de_la_socket,(char *)buffer,12,0);
    if (nombre_de_caractere_recu_capteur==SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("\nFonction modbus 3 : probleme reception trame");
    else
    {
        printf("\nTrame modbus reçue de la fonction 3 : ");
        for(i=0; i< nombre_de_caractere_recu_capteur; i++)
        {
            printf("%x ",buffer[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return buffer[10];
}

unsigned char mettreBrasEnRepos(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties)
{

    unsigned char entrees;
    entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
    printf("\n entrees = %x\n",entrees);
    if( ( entrees & BRAS_POSITION_MAGASIN) ==  BRAS_POSITION_MAGASIN)
    {
        sorties=BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLEA^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
        Sleep(1855 );
        sorties=(~BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLEA)&sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }
    if( ( entrees & BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE) ==  BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE)
    {
        sorties=BRAS_POSITION_MAGASINA^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
        Sleep(1860 );
        sorties=(~BRAS_POSITION_MAGASINA)&sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }
    return sorties;
}




unsigned char  test_reservoir_plus_action(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties )
{
    unsigned char entrees;
    int vide;


    entrees=RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE;
    if(  (entrees & RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE) ==  RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE )
    {


    }

    // Boucle d'attente reserve vide
    vide=1;


    do
    {
        entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
        printf("entrees = %x\n",entrees);
        if( ( entrees & RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE) ==  RESERVE_PIECE_VIDE)
        {
            printf("Reserve vide  !!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            vide=0;
        }

    }
    while( vide == 1 );
    printf("sorties = %X\n",sorties);
    sorties=EJECTION_PIECE^sorties;
    ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x00, sorties);  /// Probleme

    return sorties;
}


unsigned char  test_brasgauche_plus_action(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties )
{
    unsigned char entrees;



    entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
    printf("\n entrees = %x\n",entrees);
    if( ( entrees & BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE) ==  BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE)
    {
        printf("Bras n'est pas a droit \n");
    }
    else
    {

        sorties=BRAS_POSITION_MAGASINA^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }
    Sleep(3000);

    return sorties;
}


Serveur :


unsigned char  test_aspirationon_plus_action(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties )
{

    unsigned char entrees;

    entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
    printf("\n entrees = %x\n",entrees);
    if( ( entrees & ASPIRATION_ON) ==  ASPIRATION_ON)
    {
        printf("Bras n'est pas a droit \n");
    }
    else
    {
        sorties=ASPIRATION_ONA^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }

    return sorties;
}


unsigned char  test_brasdroite_plus_action(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties )
{

    unsigned char entrees;

    entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
    printf("\n entrees = %x\n",entrees);
    if( ( entrees & BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE) ==  BRAS_POSITION_MODULE_CONTROLE)
    {
        printf("Bras n'est pas a droit \n");
    }
    else
    {

        sorties=BRAS_POSITION_MAGASINA^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }
    Sleep(3000);


    return sorties;
}


unsigned char  test_aspiratiooff_plus_action(SOCKET id_de_la_socket, unsigned char sorties )
{

    unsigned char entrees;

    entrees=lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
    printf("\n entrees = %x\n",entrees);
    if( ( entrees & ASPIRATION_OFF) ==  ASPIRATION_OFF)
    {
        printf("Bras n'est pas a droit \n");
    }
    else
    {
        sorties=EXPULSION_VENTOUSE^sorties;
        ecritureModbus(id_de_la_socket,(unsigned char)0x0, sorties);
    }

    return sorties;
}



int main()
{
    unsigned char sorties=0x00;
    unsigned char sorties1=0x01;
    unsigned char entrees;
    unsigned char car='a';
    int nombre_caractere_recu_serveur;
    int nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur;
    int vide,gauche,droite,retracter,etape;

    SOCKET id_de_la_socket=configurationTCP("192.168.10.244",502);
    SOCKET id_de_la_socket2=configurationTCP("172.16.1.24",4200);


    sorties=mettreBrasEnRepos(id_de_la_socket,sorties);
    Sleep(3000);

    sorties=test_reservoir_plus_action(id_de_la_socket,sorties);

    Sleep(3000);
    sorties=test_brasgauche_plus_action(id_de_la_socket,sorties);
    Sleep(3000);
    sorties=test_aspirationon_plus_action(id_de_la_socket,sorties);
    Sleep(3000);
    sorties=test_brasdroite_plus_action(id_de_la_socket,sorties);
    Sleep(3000);
    sorties=test_aspiratiooff_plus_action(id_de_la_socket,sorties);


    /*
      //lectureModbus(id_de_la_socket,0x00, 0x01);
       printf("sorties =%x\n",car);
       // nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur=send(id_de_la_socket2,(char *)&car,1,0);  // partie envois supoervisuer ou mon serveur tcp
         nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur=send(id_de_la_socket2,(char *)"sortie=X",9,0);  // partie envois supoervisuer ou mon serveur tcp
        if (nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur==SOCKET_ERROR)

            printf("\n Desole, je n'ai pas envoyer les donnees du a l'erreur : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        else
        {

            printf("\n send donnee  Serveur  : OK : %d",nombre_de_caractere_envoi_serveur);

        }
    */

    fermetureTCP(id_de_la_socket);
    fermetureTCP(id_de_la_socket2);
    return 0;
}
```

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clib.h>

#define PORT_ECHO                        7    /*well known echo port*/
#define TCPECHOBUF_SERVER_RECVSIZE    1024


static char recvbuf[TCPECHOBUF_SERVER_RECVSIZE];
static char ClientIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];



/******************************************************************************
* main()                                                                      *
******************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
   struct sockaddr_in   addr;
   struct sockaddr_in   claddr;

   int sd;
   int asd;
   int established = 0;
   int i;
   int retval;
   int error;

   printf("\r\nTCPserver, listening on port %d\r\n",PORT_ECHO);

   sd = opensocket( SOCK_STREAM, &error );
   if(sd == API_ERROR)
   {
       printf("\r\nSocket open failed: %d",error);
       return -1;
   }

   addr.sin_family      =  PF_INET;
   addr.sin_port        =  htons(PORT_ECHO);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr =  0L;

   retval = bind( sd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, &error );
   if(retval == API_ERROR)
   {
       printf("\r\nTCPserver: Socket bind failed: %d",error);
       return -1;
   }


    /**********************************************************************
    *Listen for connections                                               *
    **********************************************************************/
     printf("\r\nTCPserver: Listening for connection");
     retval = listen( sd, 1, &error );
     if(retval == API_ERROR)
     {
         printf("\r\nTCPserver: Socket listen failed: %d",error);
         return -1;
     }
   while(1)
   {
     /**********************************************************************
     *accept, establish a connection                                       *
     **********************************************************************/
     claddr.sin_family      =  PF_INET;
     claddr.sin_port        =  0;
     claddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  0L;

     retval = accept( sd, (struct sockaddr *)&claddr, &error );
     if(retval == API_ERROR)
     {
         printf("\r\nTCPserver: Socket accept failed: %d",error);
         return -1;
     }

     //save the new socket descriptor
     asd = retval;
     established = 1;

     InetToAscii( (unsigned long *) &claddr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *) ClientIP );

     printf("\r\nTCPserver: Connected with %s , Port %u\r\n",ClientIP, htons(claddr.sin_port));
     while(established)
     {
printf("1");
       /********************************************************************
       *Wait for incoming data from the client                             *
       ********************************************************************/
       do
       {
printf("2");
          retval = recv( asd, (char *)recvbuf, TCPECHOBUF_SERVER_RECVSIZE,
          MSG_TIMEOUT, 20000L, &error );
          printf("retval=%d ",retval);
          printf("car=%c ",recvbuf[0]);
          recvbuf[0]=recvbuf[0]+1;
          if(retval == API_ERROR)
          {
             printf("\r\nTCPserver: Receive error %d",error);
             established = 0;
             break;
          }
          else
          {
             if( retval > 0)    //data received
             {
     printf("\r\nTCPserver: Received data\r\n");
     for(i=0;i<retval; i++)
     {
       printf("%02X ",(char)recvbuf[i]);
     }
     printf("\r\n");
     /********************************
      echo data back to the client
     ********************************/
     retval = send( asd, (char *)recvbuf, retval, 0, &error );
    printf("3");
     if(retval == API_ERROR)
     {
     printf("\r\nTCPserver: Send error %d",error);
     established = 0;
     break;
     }
             }
          }
          /*****************************************************************
           Check, if there is more data available at the socket
          *****************************************************************/
          retval = GetWaitingBytes( asd, &error );
       }//while data available
       while((retval!=API_ERROR) && (retval>0));
     }//while(established)


     //close socket, given from accept
     printf("\r\nTCPserver: Closing connection");
     retval = closesocket( asd, &error );
     if(retval==API_ERROR)
     {
      printf("\r\nTCPserver: Socket close failed: %d",error);
     }
   }//while(1)

   /************************************
    Shutdown server, should not happen
    ************************************/

   printf("\r\nTCPserver: Closing listening socket");
   retval = closesocket( sd, &error );
   if(retval==API_ERROR)
   {
    printf("\r\nTCPserver: Socket close failed %d",error);
   }
   return 0;
}
// End of file
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,can you tell me a little more ? I really need help

Comment: Tweak your server and client files.  Relace main() in each with 'startClient()' and 'startServer()'.  Create a third unit with a main() in the usual way, and have the main() call startClient only.  Check it still works OK as a client.  Edit main() to call  startServer only. Check it still works OK as a server.  Edit main to start a separate thread for startClient() and startServer(), then get stuck, eg on a console read loop.   Now you should have a server and client working in the same process:)

Comment: Thank you bery mutch , i cant build  my serveur code in windows , do you have any idea ? I already add the following library : 
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <clib.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in the same program". You currently have two different programs (as you have two `int main(void)` functions). You *could* use multithreading to have both the client and the server in a single executable, but I fail to see a situation in which this could be advantageous.

If you want more concrete help, I would suggest making a smaller example that exhibits more precisely how you are currently trying to use threads. Otherwise, it might be wise to look up a simple multithreading tutorial, and adding to it until it reaches the level of complexity you currently seem you have in your program.

Comment: 'but I fail to see a situation in which this could be advantageous' -   peer-to-peer networking.

Comment: From my understanding, the type of *server* in the question above is more akin to something like a torrent tracker in the case of peer-to-peer networking. But you are absolutely right, I should have thought of that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, ''but I fail to see a situation in which this could be advantageous.'' My project manager (my teacher) wants it, that both programs run in the same program  he talk me abut a  multithreading ,but I have no idea how to use this

Comment: In that case, you should consider submitting a question which includes the multithreading code you are having problems with (as there does not appear to be any in the above). I suggest reading [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm), or even better, [this one](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/) if you are allowed to use C++11 code, and try to make small steps towards your goal.